# Document and receipt management (a replacement for Neat Receips)

Tags: windows, document-management, scanning

I have been using [Neat](http://www.neat.com/products/overview/) for years for scanning and organizing my receipts, bills, tax documents, pretty much anything that would go in a filing cabinet. I found out a few days ago they will be ending support for their desktop version and are trying to push everyone to the subscription-based cloud service that I have ZERO interest in.

What are my alternatives? Basically, I am looking for some sort of digital filing cabinet that files can be organized in. Keyword searched, all documents are OCR-ed when they are scanned in, and pertinent information from the receipts is added to the database vendor, cost, tax etc. automatically.

For Windows 10.

Comment: Alfresco could do a large part of that, but what do you mean by "added to the database vendor"?

Answer (score 3):

[Paperless](https://github.com/danielquinn/paperless) is a self-hosted solution in which you push scanned documents to a folder and it automatically performs OCR and makes them searchable. I can't speak for the ease of installation, as I haven't tried it myself yet. One drawback is that the OCR'd text is not encrypted on the server (this is clearly stated on the github page).